# How to carry a bike box from the start to end of the trip?

Tags: mountain-bike, transportation

I'm planning for a cycling trip from Srinagar (starting point) to Leh (Ending point) approx 450 kms. Going to Srinagar in Flight and coming back to my city from Leh via flight only. So, I have to pack my cycle properly in cardboard box. I can take my cycle to Srinagar in a bike box and I will need to use the same box while returning from Leh. For that I have to carry the it from Srinagar to Leh somehow. There is no courier facility in that place. Can you suggest me how can I take it?

Comment: no courier facility in that place that you can find doesn't mean they don't exist, it's very likely that you can find someone local that is willing to ship it across.

Comment: Is your bike a folder?  There exist hard cases for folders that do dual-duty as trailers for your stuff once the bike is assembled.  Airnimal and Wike are two names I recall.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some possibilities:

- Some searching suggests there's at least one bike shop in Leh. You
  could call ahead and get them to save a suitable bike box for you.
- You could scrounge some suitably big pieces of cardboard once there
  and either buy or bring some packing tape. Properly reinforced, boxes
  "made" this way are totally fine for shipping bikes in.
- Finally, many airports have bike boxes for sale. The disadvantage
  with them in my experience is they're usually the enormous type that
  are intended to allow minimal disassembly but are very expensive to
  actually fly with.